# Airflow Jinja Templating - How Do I Pass query_params into my SQL file?

Tags: jinja2, airflow

I'm trying to use `BigQueryOperator` with a templated SQL file.

Inside the SQL file query, I have (e.g.) `{{ param_1 }}, {{ param_2 }}`.

My `query_params` argument is as follows:

```
query_params=[
     {'name': 'param_1',
      'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
      'parameterValue': {'value': 'value_1'}
     },
     {'name': 'param_2',
      'parameterType': {'type': 'STRING'},
      'parameterValue': {'value': 'value_2'}
     }
],
```

but no matter what I do, the parameters aren't getting passed through. The resulting SQL just has those parameters as `""`.

I've tried enclosing the `{{` in `'`, tried writing `{{ query_params.param_1 }}`, tried `params`, but I can't get it working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it. Instead of `query_params` in the operator constructor, I need to use `params` which looks like:

`params={'param_1': 'value_1', 'param_2': 'value_2'}`

and then in the SQL file, reference these as `{{ params.param_1 }}`